# What it is the difference between the flag "it should be closed for another reason…" and "needs moderator attention"?

Tags: support, flagging

I wonder when this flag "it should be closed for another reason…" should be used. Is it not the same flag as it "needs moderator attention"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "it should be closed for another reason…" flag is the flag that should be used to close a question that is not duplicating another question. In fact, the previous flag is "it is a duplicate…."
It is different from the "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" flag, since the first adds the question to the [Close Votes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/close) review queue, accessible to all the users who can vote to close; the other flag shows up the question in a queue visible only to moderators, as only moderators see those flags for which the user entered a custom reason.

That is the reason why a custom reason should be used only for specific cases that really need moderation attention.
Keep in mind that flags that are not for closing a question have as last destinatary the moderators, even though they are visible to other users as well (with the exception I reported before). You should not flag something that doesn't really need attention from moderators. (I know you already know this; the note is for future readers.)